# JS Auto select next input and detect last input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to auto jump to the next input once keypress is triggered but my code isnt working and I believe its todo with the next() select but can't seem to get it selected correctly.

HTML Form

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <div id="confirm-input">
        @csrf
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input" maxlength="1"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input" maxlength="1"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input" maxlength="1"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input" maxlength="1"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input" maxlength="1"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input" maxlength="1"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS Code

```
$('.input').keyup(function (e) {
        if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
            var next = $(this).nextAll('input').first();
            //Check if there is a next input.
            if (next.length) {
                next.focus();
            } else {
                $(this).blur
                //AJAX CALL
            }
        }
});
```

Im using nextAll() as i believe it can look outside the div but not having any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Im using nextAll() as i believe it can look outside the div but not having any luck."

That's your problem right there. `nextAll()` only looks on the same tree level in the DOM. (Plunker here to demonstrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/u5t2Oy636xvl82WIgmvp?p=preview)

One possible solution would be to give your inputs successive `id`s, so that if your current input has an `id` of, say, "input-2", the look for "input-3" as the next input to focus on.

Update:

Here's a working Plunker that illustrates the above idea: http://plnkr.co/edit/UT5HydtxzyxkTIt5LBeZ?p=preview

```
$('.input').keyup(function (e) {
  if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
    var currId = $(this).attr('id');
    var nextId = '#input-' + (Number(currId.split('-')[1]) + 1);
    var next = $(nextId);
    //Check if there is a next input.
    if (next.length) {
      next.focus();
    } else {
      $(this).blur
      //AJAX CALL
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggested solution is to determine how many elements match the selector then invoke `.focus()` using the index of each element, `.blur()` on the last element. You probably don't want to fire the AJAX call unless you've hit maxLength, hence the `else if` statement rather than just `else`.

```
var selector = "#confirm-input .input";
$(selector).keyup(function (e) {

  var i = $(this).index(selector);
  var len = $(selector).length - 1;

  if (this.value.length == this.maxLength && i < len) {
    $(selector).eq(i+1).focus();
  }

  else if(this.value.length == this.maxLength && i === len) {
    $(this).blur();
    //AJAX CALL
  }

});
```